# Magento Exception Error: Invalid method Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_View_Type_Simple::displayProductStockStatus()

Tags: magento, exception, printing, magento-1.6

i tried to install a theme to my magento system
and when i try to open a product page its shows me an error:
Exception printing is disabled by default for security reasons.

please help me

the error:

```
    Invalid method Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_View_Type_Simple::displayProductStockStatus(Array
(
)
)

Trace:
#0 /home/embxsto1/domains/emb1.xstore.co.il/public_html/app/design/frontend/default/ma_erida/template/catalog/product/view/type/default.phtml(30): Varien_Object->__call('displayProductS...', Array)
#1 /home/embxsto1/domains/emb1.xstore.co.il/public_html/app/design/frontend/default/ma_erida/template/catalog/product/view/type/default.phtml(30): Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_View_Type_Simple->displayProductStockStatus()
#2 /home/embxsto1/domains/emb1.xstore.co.il/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(241): include('/home/embxsto1/...')
#3 /home/embxsto1/domains/emb1.xstore.co.il/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(272): Mage_Core_Block_Template->fetchView('frontend/defaul...')
#4 /home/embxsto1/domains/emb1.xstore.co.il/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(286): Mage_Core_Block_Template->renderView()
#5 /home/embxsto1/domains/emb1.xstore.co.il/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(863): Mage_Core_Block_Template->_toHtml()
#6 /home/embxsto1/domains/emb1.xstore.co.il/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(582): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
#7 /home/embxsto1/domains/emb1.xstore.co.il/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(526): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->_getChildHtml('product_type_da...', true)
#8 /home/embxsto1/domains/emb1.xstore.co.il/public_html/app/design/frontend/default/ma_erida/template/catalog/product/view.phtml(56): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->getChildHtml('product_type_da...')
#9 /home/embxsto1/domains/emb1.xstore.co.il/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(241): include('/home/embxsto1/...')
#10 /home/embxsto1/domains/emb1.xstore.co.il/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(272): Mage_Core_Block_Template->fetchView('frontend/defaul...')
#11 /home/embxsto1/domains/emb1.xstore.co.il/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(286): Mage_Core_Block_Template->renderView()
#12 /home/embxsto1/domains/emb1.xstore.co.il/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(863): Mage_Core_Block_Template->_toHtml()
#13 /home/embxsto1/domains/emb1.xstore.co.il/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Text/List.php(43): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
#14 /home/embxsto1/domains/emb1.xstore.co.il/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(863): Mage_Core_Block_Text_List->_toHtml()
#15 /home/embxsto1/domains/emb1.xstore.co.il/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(582): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
#16 /home/embxsto1/domains/emb1.xstore.co.il/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(526): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->_getChildHtml('content', true)
#17 /home/embxsto1/domains/emb1.xstore.co.il/public_html/app/design/frontend/default/ma_erida/template/page/1column.phtml(52): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->getChildHtml('content')
#18 /home/embxsto1/domains/emb1.xstore.co.il/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(241): include('/home/embxsto1/...')
#19 /home/embxsto1/domains/emb1.xstore.co.il/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(272): Mage_Core_Block_Template->fetchView('frontend/defaul...')
#20 /home/embxsto1/domains/emb1.xstore.co.il/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(286): Mage_Core_Block_Template->renderView()
#21 /home/embxsto1/domains/emb1.xstore.co.il/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(863): Mage_Core_Block_Template->_toHtml()
#22 /home/embxsto1/domains/emb1.xstore.co.il/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(529): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
#23 /home/embxsto1/domains/emb1.xstore.co.il/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(391): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->getOutput()
#24 /home/embxsto1/domains/emb1.xstore.co.il/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Cms/Helper/Page.php(132): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->renderLayout()
#25 /home/embxsto1/domains/emb1.xstore.co.il/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Cms/Helper/Page.php(52): Mage_Cms_Helper_Page->_renderPage(Object(Mage_Cms_IndexController), 'no-route')
#26 /home/embxsto1/domains/emb1.xstore.co.il/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Cms/controllers/IndexController.php(75): Mage_Cms_Helper_Page->renderPage(Object(Mage_Cms_IndexController), 'no-route')
#27 /home/embxsto1/domains/emb1.xstore.co.il/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(420): Mage_Cms_IndexController->noRouteAction()
#28 /home/embxsto1/domains/emb1.xstore.co.il/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php(250): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('noRoute')
#29 /home/embxsto1/domains/emb1.xstore.co.il/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(176): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
#30 /home/embxsto1/domains/emb1.xstore.co.il/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(349): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
#31 /home/embxsto1/domains/emb1.xstore.co.il/public_html/app/Mage.php(640): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#32 /home/embxsto1/domains/emb1.xstore.co.il/public_html/index.php(81): Mage::run('', 'store')
#33 {main}
```

Comment: What about trying to enable exception printing (I guess there may be some configuration variable for that), thus getting the exception thrown?

Comment: I got the same error and @Gaurang P solution works perfectly, but no answer selected as accepted? Doesn't work fine for you?

Answer (score 8):

You can check what exception occurred in your Magento system by navigating through:

- **[Document_Root]/var/report** folder and
- Open the file # corresponding to exception number on your browser's screen.

or

you can enable exception printing for debugging purposes by:

- Open **[Document_Root]/errors** folder
- Rename **local.xml.sample** to **local.xml**

Both ways are helpful to trace and debug exceptions and errors in Magento.

Comment: Do it the first way on dev systems only, on live systems, the second way is a security leak unless you undo it for production. Google dorks everywhere of cached Magento pages, some of the errors can expose your database & login credentials. Takes little effort to fire up an SFTP client and read the file.

Answer (score 3):

**Here is the solution:**

1) Navigate to the "errors" folder.

2) Change local.xml.sample to local.xml

3) You should now see a new list of crazy errors all over the Magento page - this is okay.

4) Open magento/lib/Zend/Cache/Backend/File.php and look for:

```
protected $_options = array(
'cache_dir' => 'null',
```

5) Change it to:

```
protected $_options = array(
'cache_dir' => 'tmp/',
```

6) Save it.

Comment: This is a security leak unless you undo it for live production websites. Google dorks everywhere of cached Magento pages, some of the errors can expose your database & login credentials. Takes little effort to fire up an SFTP client and read the file.

Answer (score 2):

I face this problem , the easy and 100% working solution is remove the cache files .

In magneto folder go var/cache

Then delete all files , and refresh your site

:-)

Answer (score 2):

The Easy and 100% working solution is  **rename cache file**.

In magneto root folder **var/cache**

Then **rename cache file** name , and refresh your site.

Comment: Cheers, that did the trick for me :) Was still getting re-directed to the online version as apose to the offline version (backup) of my website.

Answer (score 0):

There are 3 things you can do to fix this issue.
1. Delete cache folder
Do this first, 90% you will get the error fixed.
First, go to root folder var/cache
delete/rename magento cache

Now you can rename or just remove all cache files, and refresh your Magento site to see if the error is gone.

2. Read log of Magento
   As you can see the error message: Error log record number: xxxxxxxxxx, here xxxxxxxxxx is the name of log file we need to check. All error log files are located in Magento/var/report folder, just open file manager and go to that folder and find the corresponding file and read the log to find solution.
3. Enable error printing 
   If the solution above doesn’t help, you can enable printing errors to check what problems caused the error. To do this follows these steps:

Step 1: go to folder  Magento/errors

There you will see  local.xml.sample  file, just rename it to  local.xml , the purpose of this action is to enable error printing in Magento

Step 2: Reload the error page and you will see the full list of error message, this will help you fix the issue.

Those steps are mentioned in [this tutorial](http://magentoexplorer.com/magento-exception-printing-is-disabled-by-default-for-security-reasons-how-to-fix), you can take a look. Hope this helps