# How to resolve the Exception printing error in magento 1.9?

Tags: magento-1.9

Exception printing is disabled by default for security reasons.

Error log record number: 44219688

Comment: possible duplicate of [magento error : "exception printing is disabled by default for security reasons](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24228487/magento-error-exception-printing-is-disabled-by-default-for-security-reasons)

Answer (score 0):

check your

> magentofolder\var\report\44219688

open the file with notepad or something. and you will read the warning / error message for that.